# Calculate duration of diferent Windows Tasks

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to know the duration of a certain task inside TaskManager to calculate from "Created Task Process" to "Task completed"?
Task Manager only show the Last Run Time but not the duration of all execution.

Thanks

Comment: add to the start a line of code to start a transcript ... and one at the end to shut the transcript off. that will give you the data in a format that can be easily parsed. ///// another option would be to use some simple logging with "just now started" and "just about to end" timestamps saved to a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for the start time of a process in the task manager then you can use something like this:

```
Get-Process | select name, starttime
```

If you're creating the task yourself then you could put a timestamp in the script (for start and finish) with something like:

```
Get-Date
```